# How to prevent Firestore documents being deleted / modified, but allow all reads and writes

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have an ios app which stores data on Firestore, and I am okay with literally anyone reading or writing data.  What I don't want to allow is the modification or deleting of data.  How can I write that into my security rules without using authentication?  Basically, I get the warning, "Your security rules are defined as public, so anyone can steal, modify, or delete data in your database." Above my rules.  Thanks!  My current rules are not specific at all, is just says "allow read, write;".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid that message, you should do two things:

1. Remove the recursive wildcard pattern "/{document=**}" that matches all documents, and instead call out each individual collection to assign specific permissions.
2. Change the types of [granular permissions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#granular_operations) that you want to allow, as described in the documentation

```
match /collection1/{id} {
  allow read, create;
}
```

Repeat that for each collection.

I do strongly recommend that you thoroughly [read the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started) to understand how rules work, as they are the biggest liability for many apps.

Comment: thank you.  So that will allow the granular permissions that I say, but not allow anything else, right?  Also, I will be sure to read the documentation.  Thanks. EDIT: Also, how do I make it official to Firebase that I have updated my security rules?  I needed to change it today because the 30 days for reading and writing since creating the firebase project without updating security rules expired.  I have pressed publish, but in my app simulator I am still denied when retrieving the data with the error: Domain=FIRFirestoreErrorDomain Code=7 "Missing or insufficient permissions." Thanks again

Comment: It sounds like your rules are not set in the way that your code requires.  If you have a new question about your actual rules, please post a new question with both the rules and the code that doesn't work with them.

Comment: Ok, here is that question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64179243/xcode-firestore-error-domain-firfirestoreerrordomain-code-7-missing-or-insuffi